# Android Built-In Animations on Emulator with 4.0

Tags: android

My app has been working on a 4.0 emulator when targeted for V11 and built with the support library Fragment classes to work from V7 and up. But now that I am targeting V14 (also min SDK), I am getting the following fatal error on fragment transition animations:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1098): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: alpha
E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:93)
```

This is the code that specifies the fragment transaction:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = mFrag.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out,
        android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(mParentId, frag);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Has something changed that these animations would no longer be found? Does it have something to do with not using the support library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `android.R.animator.fade_in` instead of `android.R.anim.fade_in`

Comment: You're correct: this fixed it. Thanks! It's always the most frustrating thing during development when something that used to work now breaks, and you swear you "haven't changed anything" in that area :-). I'm just wondering why I had to do this; is it related to using the "native" fragment support instead of the library? Was this difference noted in release notes somewhere?